# Javascript - How to know the exact length from a Js path in devtools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

So let's say I'm trying to get the *exact* length (in character) from the output of a js path, on chrome://downloads page:

```
document.querySelector("body > downloads-manager").shadowRoot.querySelector("#downloadsList > downloads-item:nth-child(2)").shadowRoot.querySelector("#description")
```

This is the js path from a test download I did, with the remaining time for the download to finish.

[image]

This is the result I got. Now, if I run that in the devtools, it will return/output the description of the remaining time of the download as mentioned above. What I want from this, is how to get the length of said output (since it changes depending on the remaining time...).

By length, I do mean length in character, for example:

```
test
```

Will be of 4 char in length...

How do I get the aforementioned length from the output of the mentioned js path, when being run in devtools?

Comment: lenght !== length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this very page, `document.querySelector('h1').innerText.length` returns 68 in Chrome Dev Tools, because the title of this question is 68 chars long. Is that what you had in mind?

You can use use innerHTML instead of innerText as well, but I think innerText is what you're looking for in this case.